# Как перевести данные из Calendar в Date?

Tags: android, android-studio, дата

Для теста, вызываю календарь для выбора даты

layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView android:id="@+id/currentDateTime"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textSize="18sp" />

<Button android:id="@+id/dateButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Изменить дату"
        android:onClick="setDate"  />
```

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView currentDateTime;
Calendar dateAndTime=Calendar.getInstance();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    currentDateTime=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.currentDateTime);
    setInitialDateTime();
}

// окно для выбора даты
public void setDate(View v) {
    new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, d,
            dateAndTime.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            dateAndTime.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            dateAndTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
            .show();
}

// установка текущей даты для textview
private void setInitialDateTime()
{
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd - MM - yyyy");
    String date = sdf.format(new Date().getTime());
    currentDateTime.setText(date);
}

//обработчик выбора даты
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        dateAndTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        dateAndTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        dateAndTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        setInitialDateTime();
    }
};
}
```

как перевести данные этого календаря в формат Date ? что бы можно было сохранить выбранную дату в БД SQL 
Грубо говоря, я хочу заполнять textview датой из бд, ну а что бы записать в бд дату её нужно как то преобразовать из формата календаря

В результате полученных ответов часть кода превратилась в

```
    private void setInitialDateTime()
{
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd - MM - yyyy");
    String date = sdf.format(dateAndTime.getTime());
    currentDateTime.setText(date);
}
```

Comment: [`dateAndTime.getTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого есть метод `getTime()` у объекта `Calendar`.

Comment: спасибо, все заработало, в вопросе добавил кусочек измененного кода

Answer (score 1):

Уточню ответы коллег.

Надо не забыть учесть, что метод `getTime()` возвращает `Date` нормированную к UTC/Гринвичу, в то время как `Calendar` содержит в себе текущую временную зону (`TimeZone`), иными словами это означает, что возвращенный `getTime()` объект `Date` теряет информацию о временной зоне.

[Подробнее здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26678030/calendar-returns-date-in-wrong-time-zone)

Это не хорошо и не плохо - просто надо держать в голове.

Comment: спасибо за уточнение, полезная информация

Comment: "теряет" -- это как-то слишком угрожающе звучит :) Я бы сказал "не содержит".